# How to show that if $f_{k}(x)=kxe^{-kx}$, {$f_k$} converges to the zero function?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

$f_{k}(x)=kxe^{-kx}$ for all $x\ge0$ and $k\ge1$, how to show {$f_k$} converges to the zero function on $[0,\infty)$ pointwise?

By L'hospital's Rule we can show that: $\lim_{x\to\infty}xe^{-x}=0$. Could we write $\lim_{k\to\infty}kxe^{-kx}=0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to show is $\lim_{k \to \infty} kxe^{-kx} = 0$ for all $x \geq 0$ using l'Hopital's rule. This is analogous as $\lim_{x \to \infty} kxe^{-kx} = 0$.

Comment: but we want to show $f_k \to f$ as $k \to \infty$

Comment: @Maggie Mak $f_k \to f$ is ambiguous. Do you mean uniform convergence? Pointwise convergence? a.e. convergence? In this case, showing $\lim_{k \to \infty} f_k(x) = f(x)$ for every $x$ establishes the pointwise convergence.

Comment: I want to show $f_k \to f$ as $k \to \infty$ where $f$ is the zero function. It is pointwise convergence but not uniformly convergence.

Comment: @Maggie Mak Yes, and that is equivalent to $\lim_{k \to \infty} f_k(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can fix $x\in [0,\infty)$ and observe that, we have $e^{kx}=1+kx+(kx)^{2}+o(kx)^{3}$,

so that, if $k>0$

$kxe^{-kx}\leq\frac{kx}{1+kx+(kx)^{2}}\to 0$ as $k\to \infty$